Centering in split environment
I got the following code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}

Sei $\mathfrak X$ ein topologischer Raum. Zwei Wege $\alpha,\beta$ mit gemeinsamem Anfangspunkt $x_0$  
und gemeinsamem Endpunkt $x_1$ in $\mathfrak X$ heißen \emph{homotop}, geschrieben $\alpha \simeq \beta$,   
falls eine stetige Abbildung $h:[0,1]\times [0,1] \to \mathfrak X$ existiert, die 
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
        \begin{split}
            h(t,0) &= \alpha(t), \\
            h(t,1) &= \beta(t), 
        \end{split}
        \qquad 
        \begin{split}
            h(0,\tau) &= x_0, \\
            h(1,\tau) &= x_1.
        \end{split}\\
        h(t,\tau) \  \text{ist ein Weg in } \mathfrak X 
        \end{split}
    \end{equation}
    erfüllt. 
\end{document}

Is there any way to center the line $h(t,\tau) \  \text{ist ein Weg in } \mathfrak X$ in the middle of the other split environment? Maybe I need to split up the text line?

You're using the wrong tools: gathered and aligned are your friends.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}

Sei $\mathfrak{X}$ ein topologischer Raum. Zwei Wege $\alpha,\beta$ mit gemeinsamem Anfangspunkt $x_0$
und gemeinsamem Endpunkt $x_1$ in $\mathfrak{X}$ heißen \emph{homotop}, geschrieben $\alpha \simeq \beta$,
falls eine stetige Abbildung $h:[0,1]\times [0,1] \to \mathfrak{X}$ existiert, die
\begin{equation}
  \begin{gathered}
    \begin{aligned}
      h(t,0) &= \alpha(t), &  h(0,\tau) &= x_0, \\
      h(t,1) &= \beta(t),  &  h(1,\tau) &= x_1.
    \end{aligned}
    \\
    h(t,\tau) \text{ ist ein Weg in } \mathfrak{X}
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
erfüllt.

\end{document}


The syntax \mathfrak X isn't correct, although it seems to work. Do prefer \mathfrak{X} that's clearer.

That's very neat, thanks! I know it isn't correct, but I get lazy from time to time and leave out the {} when using something like \mathhbb{R} or \mathfrak{X}.
